# Finding all matches to a query without using findall/3 in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I am given a database and I am querying the database with a predicate

```
findmin(A,B,course(X,Y)):- course(X,Y),X >= A,Y =< B.
```

I have my database like,

```
course(a1,b1).
course(a2,b2).
course(a3,b3).
...
```

Now instead of using standard `findall/3`predicate, I want to use my own findall,

```
finda(X,findmin(A,B,X),L)
```

If i use a recursion that will always take me to the beginning of database, I'm not getting how to use findmin recursively to give me distinct occurrences in database.

Comment: I guess you also don't want to use `bagof`, `setof`, `findall/4` and `findnsols` (the last two might be SWI specific, but am not sure).

Comment: yeah i don't want to use any inbuilt predicates

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog findall Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647758/prolog-findall-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use a *failure-driven loop* with *side-effects*. In the case of a `findall` implementation, this can broadly be achieved like this:

```
finda(X, Goal, Xs) :-
    % execute the goal to produce the binding for X
    Goal,
    % assert the result to the database (the 'side-effect')
    assert_to_db(..., Goal, ...)
    % deliberately fail, forcing Goal to be re-evaluated
    fail. 
finda(_X, _Goal, Xs) :-
    % retrieve the result from the cache and clear it
    retrieve(..., Xs, ...).
```

For a full implementation, [see this response on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22506952/206428).