# How to generate a output with the list of permutations of a set in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Code:

```
del( A, [A|B], B ).
del( A, [B|C], [B|D] ) :-
    del( A, C, D ).

same_set( [], [] ).
same_set( A, [B|C] ) :-
    del( B, A, D ), 
    same_set( D, C).
```

Current output:

```
?- mesmo_conjunto([1,a,3], Xs).
Xs = [1, a, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 3, a] ;
Xs = [a, 1, 3] ;
Xs = [a, 3, 1] ;
Xs = [3, 1, a] ;
Xs = [3, a, 1] ;
false.
```

What must be changed in the code so that it has the output below?

Expected output:

```
Xs=[[1,a,3],[1,3,a],[a,1,3],[a,3,1],[3,a,1],[3,1,a]]
```

Comment: You want to swap around the last two? Why?

Comment: In fact I want my output to immediately list all possible permutations.
Xs=[[1,a,3],[1,3,a],[a,1,3],[a,3,1],[3,a,1],[3,1,a]]

Comment: Your current code gives all of the combinations already.

Comment: Yes, my code already provides all permutations. However, he printed invidually.

I want my output to be a list of all permutations.

Comment: Oh, I see. `findall(X, mesmo_conjunto([1,a,3], X),Xs).`

Comment: You cannot use Prolog's findall/3 in the code. I have to create the code without using libraries.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gathering all solutions without findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492633/gathering-all-solutions-without-findall)

Comment: Does not reply. The code must pass the following test.


    test(mesmo_conjunto, set(Xs=[[1,a,3],[1,3,a],[a,1,3],[a,3,1],[3,a,1],[3,1,a]])) :-
        mesmo_conjunto([1,a,3], Xs).
    test(uniao_conjunto2,fail) :-
        mesmo_conjunto([1,a,3,4], [1,3,4]).

Comment: Where's that in your question?